# How to Count The Number Of Columns Of An AdaptativeGridView

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface, uwp, grid-layout

I need to apply a horizontal separator line bwteen items, when columns number change. So, it's necessary to get the number of columns of this UWP AdaptativeGridView, inside a SizeChanged event.

AdaptiveGridView have a "CalculateColumns" method, but it's not accessible.

I tried to calculate using the code below, but didn't worked as I expected:

```
        var twoColumns = Math.Abs(AppWebsiteGridView.DesiredWidth - (AppWebsiteGridView.ActualWidth / 2));

        var oneColumn = Math.Abs(AppWebsiteGridView.ActualWidth - AppWebsiteGridView.DesiredWidth);

        var threeColumns = Math.Abs(AppWebsiteGridView.DesiredWidth - (AppWebsiteGridView.ActualWidth / 3));

        var numberOfItems = AppWebsiteGridView.Items.Count;

        if (AppWebsiteGridView.Items[numberOfItems - 1] is SignInModel lastItem && AppWebsiteGridView.Items[numberOfItems - 2] is SignInModel lastButOneItem
            && AppWebsiteGridView.Items[numberOfItems - 3] is SignInModel lastButTwoItem)
        {
            if (threeColumns < twoColumns)
            {
                lastItem.IsEndLine = false;
                lastButOneItem.IsEndLine = false;
                lastButTwoItem.IsEndLine = false;
            }

            else if (twoColumns < oneColumn)
            {
                lastItem.IsEndLine = false;
                lastButOneItem.IsEndLine = false;
                lastButTwoItem.IsEndLine = true;
            }

            else
            {
                lastItem.IsEndLine = false;
                lastButOneItem.IsEndLine = true;
                lastButTwoItem.IsEndLine = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the source code of the `AdaptiveGridView` here: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/63cbb4a51bdef59083ccfc86bbcba41f966d0027/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.Primitives/AdaptiveGridView/AdaptiveGridView.Properties.cs#L152

The `CalculateColumns` method is calculating the columns based on **containerWidth** and **itemWidth**. The **itemWidth** parameter is the `DesiredWidth` and the **containerWidth** parameter is the actual width of the `AdaptiveGridView`. So what you need to do is just use the method in your own code-behind:

```
 private static int CalculateColumns(double containerWidth, double itemWidth)
    {
        var columns = (int)Math.Round(containerWidth / itemWidth);
        if (columns == 0)
        {
            columns = 1;
        }

        return columns;
    }
```